# Not able to get token for office365 onenote

Tags: onenote

I am trying to get access token using WebAuthenticationCoreManager for my native UWP application (Windows 10), am using https://www.onenote.com as the resource.

Before requesting for the token I have associated my app with azure and using client id generating from it.

I have also provided necessary delegated permissions for office365api to my application on azure.

I am getting error with code AADSTS65005 with a message "he request has failed because the client has not specified this resource in its requiredResourceAccess list".

Am I missing some steps that needs to be followed?[delegated permission snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8c6O.png)

Answer (score 0):

The resource URI is https://onenote.com/
Please try with that.